# Registering an optional custom post type from a plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, customization

I see the codex notes to call flush_rewrite_rules() on plugin activation and deactivation when registering a custom post type from a plugin but I'm looking for the best practice if a plugin gives users the option to register a custom post type. In other words, the custom post type would be registered only if a setting is set. Should I just register the custom post type anyway and and hide it from the menu or not make it public unless they choose the appropriate setting?

Comment: You can create a settings page in admin dashboard using settings API and add a checkbox in it. Then register the CPT conditionally only if the check box is checked.

Comment: the more important is to not call `flush_rewrite_rules` at every page load. if you call it just when the option is selected or unselectecd, it's acceptable